# Explanation for Flask-WTF please

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

this is my code for password_check and everything is working great but i don't fully understand why i need to put second parameter inside brackets def password_check(form,field): in order my function to work. when i remove field from brackets it doesn't work anymore
here is my code

```py
import re
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import EqualTo, InputRequired, Email, ValidationError
from models import User

def password_check(form,field):
    password = form.password.data
    if len(password)< 4:
        raise ValidationError('Password must be at lest 8 letters long')
    elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
        raise ValidationError('Password must contain a number')
    elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
        raise ValidationError('Password must have one uppercase letter')

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(message='Please enter Your name')])
    lastname = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(message='Please enter Your lastname')])
    email = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(),password_check])
    confirm_pass = PasswordField( validators=[InputRequired(),EqualTo('password', message='Passwords 
    must match')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question is not clear, can you [edit] your question to show what you mean by putting it "in brackets" vs "not in brackets"?

Comment: when i remove 'field' from here -->   def password_check(form,field):   @G.Anderson

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? When you remove `field`, does it throw an error when you try to run your code, or does it just not do anything? If an error, please provide the full traceback of the error

Comment: That makes a bit more sense - I've added the specific part of the documentation to my Answer; they're required because they're passed in as arguments to each validator in the sequence

Comment: @G.Anderson this is a error code when i remove 'field': password_check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `validators` argument to `StringField()` expects some sort of [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (in your case you're passing in a `list`, but I suspect anything iterable should work)

From the [docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#the-field-base-class)

> validators – A sequence of validators to call when validate is called.

`form` and `field` are required arguments to your validator simply because they're passed to each validator .. per the [Custom validators docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#custom-validators) (emphasis mine)

> All we’ve done here is move the exact same code out of the class and as a function. Since a validator can be any callable which accepts the **two positional arguments form and field**, this is perfectly fine, but the validator is very special-cased.